# How can I read a vector of structures in a mapped-file?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-mapped-files

I have 2 programs, one gets all processes information using Windows API and stores them in a vector of structure like this:

```
struct Info{
  int pid,ppid;
  char exeName[256];
}
```

I keep back_pushing structure in vector when i populate a structure with data.
Now, I've tried to use `memcpy()` to memorize data in mapped-file but I can't read it properly in the second program. Can you help me to figure out how to read data properly?

Code program 1:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <vector>

struct InfoProces {
    DWORD pid;
    DWORD ppid;
    char  exeName[256];
};

int main(){
    HANDLE hProcesses;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    hProcesses = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    if (hProcesses == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot failed. err = %d", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (!Process32First(hProcesses, &pe32)) {
        printf("Process32First failed. err = %d", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hProcesses);
        return -1;
    }

    
    HANDLE hdata = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1024 * 1024, "data");
    if (hdata == NULL) {
        printf("Can't create a file mapping. err = %d", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char* pdata = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hdata, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    if (pdata == NULL) {
        printf("cant get pointer to mapping file. err = %d", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    

    do {
        InfoProces pi;
        pi.pid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
        pi.ppid = pe32.th32ParentProcessID;
        strcpy(pi.exeName, pe32.szExeFile);
        
        
    } while (Process32Next(hProcesses, &pe32));
    

    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hProcesses);
    return 0;
```

Code program 2:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

struct InfoProces {
    DWORD pid;
    DWORD ppid;
    char  exeName[256];
};

int main() 
{
    HANDLE hdata = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, false, "data");

    unsigned char* pdata = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hdata, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if (pdata == NULL) {
        printf("cant get pointer to mapped file. err = %d", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    std::vector<InfoProces>processes;

    memcpy(&processes,pdata,sizeof(data));

    for (std::vector<InfoProces>::iterator i = processes.begin(); i < processes.end(); i++)
        printf("Process[%d](parinte[%d]): %s\n", i->pid, i->ppid, i->exeName);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your approach.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I added the code in the post, feel free to check it out

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.

You cannot scanf into a vector, there is so much wrong this code. You use the WinAPI for file access, which is complex and error prone. The best and easiest thing to do is probably read tutorials about I/O in C++ using the STL and reimplement it using the fstream class. Obtain the process informations you need with the WinAPI, but do the I/O with the STL. Also you are missing some basic C++ knowlege, because you mix C and C++ functions/classes in an evil way. Just dig through some tutorials, it will help you.

Comment: @lars oh, sorry. I was testing something else there. I modified that now.

Comment: You are never using `pdata` to store your data. Why are you expecting your target program to read anything? And once you fix that, how are you going to let the target program know, how much data it can read? You are still looking for a robust way to serialize data, as you were told [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777680/how-to-read-and-write-to-mapped-file#comment114543441_64777680).

Comment: @IInspectable sorry i fixed the variable. I was thinking I can avoid serialization..

Comment: If the goal is to serialize data, trying to avoid serializing data isn't going to be part of the solution. Regardless, your "writer" still isn't writing anything into the file-mapping. It merely populates a local variable, and then lets it go right away. Neither C nor C++ are languages where guessing will get you anywhere.

Comment: @IInspectable then, can I write a structure one by one in the mapped-file and read structures 1 by 1 modifying the pointer?

Comment: So long as you allow the client to know when it reached the end of the sequence is, and follow C++' intricate type-casting rules, that's perfectly doable. Though a memory-mapped file is not quite the most obvious choice to implement a FIFO queue.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment pointed out, you have got the starting address of the mapped view(`pdata`), You can only use the `pdata` for memory sharing, but not any stack address of the process.
Try to copy the memory of `InfoProces` to the `pdata` in program 1:

```
memcpy(pdata, &pi, sizeof(InfoProces));
```

In addition, in program 2, you did not set the size for the vector, and you should replace `&processes` with `processes.data()`. You also need to know the size of the array you added in program 1:

```
std::vector<InfoProces> processes;
processes.resize(count);
memcpy(processes.data(), pdata, sizeof(InfoProces)*count);
```

Following code works for me.

Program 1:(Record the count of `InfoProces` and save it to a DWORD in the beginning of `pdata`)

```
...
unsigned char* pdata = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hdata, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
if (pdata == NULL) {
    printf("cant get pointer to mapping file. err = %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

unsigned char* begin = pdata;

//offset a size of DWORD;
DWORD count = 0;
pdata += sizeof(DWORD);

do {
    InfoProces pi;
    pi.pid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
    pi.ppid = pe32.th32ParentProcessID;
    strcpy(pi.exeName, pe32.szExeFile);
    memcpy(pdata, &pi, sizeof(InfoProces));
    pdata += sizeof(InfoProces);
    count++;
} while (Process32Next(hProcesses, &pe32));

memcpy(begin, &count, sizeof(DWORD));

getchar();
UnmapViewOfFile(begin);
CloseHandle(hdata);
CloseHandle(hProcesses);
...
```

Program 2:

```
...
unsigned char* pdata = (unsigned char*)MapViewOfFile(hdata, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
if (pdata == NULL) {
    printf("cant get pointer to mapped file. err = %d", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
unsigned char* begin = pdata;
DWORD count = 0;
memcpy(&count, pdata, sizeof(DWORD));
pdata += sizeof(DWORD);

std::vector<InfoProces> processes;
processes.resize(count);
memcpy(processes.data(), pdata, sizeof(InfoProces)*count);

for (std::vector<InfoProces>::iterator i = processes.begin(); i < processes.end(); i++)
    printf("Process[%d](parinte[%d]): %s\n", i->pid, i->ppid, i->exeName);
UnmapViewOfFile(begin);
CloseHandle(hdata);
...
```

Finally, do not forget to close the handle and unmap address.

Comment: Hi,@IceCreamMachine did this answer work for you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help to you.